# Removing ActionBar (Tittle) splash screen with icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

just started to developing with action bar. Having this problem. I have customized action bar as I wanted ( sort of, still cant position buttons on the left :)). I have removed Icons, back button, tittle from action bar. 
Problem is, that when I'm launching application Tittle bar (with icon and tittle) flashes for a second, before customized action bar appear...
How can i stop that splash?

I have saw some answers that include removing TittleBar from android theme, but because TittleBar and ActionBar are basically the same thing, removing TittleBar causes ActionBar to dissapear.

Comment: Use non action bar theme for the activity if you don't want one

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove your ActionBar in one Activity in particular, the best way to deal with it is to use Theme.

In you AndroidManifest, declare your application with the Theme of you app, and you can declare Activity with one Theme in particular :

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoTitle"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>


   <!-- ... YOUR OTHERS ACTIVITIES -->


</application>
```

in your styles.xml :

```
<!-- Application theme. -->   
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeFullScreen" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```